# Mysql Innodb, fetching parent rows and their children in order for rendering in an ul

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure:

Notice that the field fk_parent_group_id can either be NULL for root groups, or be the id of a root group. Groups with fk_parent_group_id that is NOT NULL cannot have child groups.

I am trying to render the data as follows:

```
16  Module 1    0   5       1
19  Submodule 1 0       16  1
20  Submodule 2 0       16  1
22  Submodule 3 0       16  1
24  Module 2    0           1
25  Module 3    0           1
26  Submodule 4 0       25  1
27  Submodule 5 0       25  1
28  Submodule 6 0       25  1
29  Module 4    0           1
30  Module 5    1           1
31  Module 6    0           1
```

Coincidentally the data has been entered in the correct way I want it output, I would like to output formatted for a JavaScript accordion style widget, in a series of unordered lists:

  Module 1
  - Submodule 1
  - Submodule 2
  - Submodule 3
  ...

Effectively I would like to select a root group followed by it's child groups.

Sorry if I've put too much information in here, I've tried joining on itself but can't get that to work at all!

Comment: I would recommend two tables, one for modules and one for submodules. That way your queries would be much easier to write and maintain.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a viable solution, other parts of the system have already been written dependant on a single primary key.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a column identifying a module as a parent or a child? If you can do that then the solution is simple.

Comment: Possibly, currently parents are identified by having fk_parent_group_id IS NULL, while children are fk_parent_group_id IS NOT NULL

Comment: If that is the case then you should be able to: SELECT * FROM group WHERE fk_parent_group_id IS NULL; iterate through your results doing SELECT * FROM group WHERE fk_parent_group_id=<THE ID FROM YOUR RESULT>; Build your objects as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM group ORDER BY CONCAT_WS('_', fk_parent_group_id, id)
```

Comment: @SpabbyPHP: Actually, on reflection, this would be much faster (as there's no messing around with strings): `ORDER BY IFNULL(fk_parent_group_id, id), IF(fk_parent_group_id IS NULL, NULL, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, let me know:

I create a table with the important fields (id, module, module son) and I filled out with some dumb data and this is What I have.

```
mysql> show create table groups\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: groups
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modu` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into groups (id,modu,sub_group) values (16,'Module 1',null),
    -> (19,'Submodule 1' ,16),
    -> (20,'Submodule 2' , 16),
    -> (22,'Submodule 3' , 16),
    -> (24,'Module 2',null),
    -> (25,'Module 3',null),
    -> (26,'Submodule 4', 25),
    -> (27,'Submodule 5', 25),
    -> (28,'Submodule 6', 25);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from groups;
+------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | modu        | sub_group |
+------+-------------+-----------+
|   16 | Module 1    |      NULL |
|   19 | Submodule 1 |        16 |
|   20 | Submodule 2 |        16 |
|   22 | Submodule 3 |        16 |
|   24 | Module 2    |      NULL |
|   25 | Module 3    |      NULL |
|   26 | Submodule 4 |        25 |
|   27 | Submodule 5 |        25 |
|   28 | Submodule 6 |        25 |
+------+-------------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the important Thing is the query I applied a "self-join" and it looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from groups as t1 join groups as t2  on t1.id=t2.sub_group;
+------+----------+-----------+------+-------------+-----------+
| id   | modu     | sub_group | id   | modu        | sub_group |
+------+----------+-----------+------+-------------+-----------+
|   16 | Module 1 |      NULL |   19 | Submodule 1 |        16 |
|   16 | Module 1 |      NULL |   20 | Submodule 2 |        16 |
|   16 | Module 1 |      NULL |   22 | Submodule 3 |        16 |
|   25 | Module 3 |      NULL |   26 | Submodule 4 |        25 |
|   25 | Module 3 |      NULL |   27 | Submodule 5 |        25 |
|   25 | Module 3 |      NULL |   28 | Submodule 6 |        25 |
+------+----------+-----------+------+-------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you want to simplify the result:

```
mysql> select t1.id as ID, t1.modu as PARENT, t2.modu as SON from groups as t1 join groups as t2  on t1.id=t2.sub_group;
+------+----------+-------------+
| ID   | PARENT   | SON         |
+------+----------+-------------+
|   16 | Module 1 | Submodule 1 |
|   16 | Module 1 | Submodule 2 |
|   16 | Module 1 | Submodule 3 |
|   25 | Module 3 | Submodule 4 |
|   25 | Module 3 | Submodule 5 |
|   25 | Module 3 | Submodule 6 |
+------+----------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will only display the modules with Children:

If you want to display all of them you can do this

```
mysql> select t1.id as ID, t1.modu as PARENT, t2.modu as SON from groups as t1 join groups as t2  on t1.id=IFNULL(t2.sub_group,t2.id);
+------+----------+-------------+
| ID   | PARENT   | SON         |
+------+----------+-------------+
|   16 | Module 1 | Module 1    |
|   16 | Module 1 | Submodule 1 |
|   16 | Module 1 | Submodule 2 |
|   16 | Module 1 | Submodule 3 |
|   24 | Module 2 | Module 2    |
|   25 | Module 3 | Module 3    |
|   25 | Module 3 | Submodule 4 |
|   25 | Module 3 | Submodule 5 |
|   25 | Module 3 | Submodule 6 |
+------+----------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

or this way

```
mysql> select t1.id as ID, t1.modu as PARENT, if(t2.modu=t1.id,NULL,t2.sub_group) as SON from groups as t1 join groups as t2  on t1.id=IFNULL(t2.sub_group,t2.id);
+------+----------+------+
| ID   | PARENT   | SON  |
+------+----------+------+
|   16 | Module 1 | NULL |
|   16 | Module 1 |   16 |
|   16 | Module 1 |   16 |
|   16 | Module 1 |   16 |
|   24 | Module 2 | NULL |
|   25 | Module 3 | NULL |
|   25 | Module 3 |   25 |
|   25 | Module 3 |   25 |
|   25 | Module 3 |   25 |
+------+----------+------+
9 rows in set, 9 warnings (0.00 sec)
```